# Правила именования миграций,таблиц в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Какие правила к именам у миграций и таблиц в Rails 4? 
Так же хотелось бы поглубже узнать о остальных принятых соглашениях об именах различных сущностей у Rails в рамках "Convention Over Configuration"...

Answer (score 4):

Название миграции влияет исключительно на то, что выдаст генератор миграций. Вам ничто не мешает после завершения его работы переписать миграцию полностью на свой лад, Rails и слова поперёк не скажет.

Но автоматическое наполнение может сэкономить немного времени. Правил всего три, [их можно запросто найти в исходниках](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ff044c3c3a0a85d26d7c000abeeed835a3bee0bf/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb#L24) (там производится поиск по сформированному имени файла), берётся первое же совпадение:

- ### Добавление/удаление полей:

  ```
  (Add|Remove) (игнорируется) (To|From) (НазваниеТаблицы)
  AddNameToUser
  ```

  Указанные после команды спецификации полей (`название[:тип[:свойства]]`, например, `name:string:index`) будут, соответственно, добавлены или удалены в указанной таблице.
- ### Join table:

  ```
  (игнорируется) (JoinTable) (игнорируется)
  CreateJoinTableForUsersAndGroups
  ```

  Когда и только когда после этого указано два атрибута, генератор пытается опознать в них названия таблиц и сделать для них join table (для `has_and_belongs_to_many`).
- ### Создание таблицы:

  ```
  (Create) (НазваниеТаблицы)
  CreateUsers
  ```

  Обратить внимание стоит только на то, что пример к предыдущему правилу подходит и к этому. Но используется предыдущее, потому что оно расположено выше и проверяется раньше.

Запоминать это, наверное, нет смысла. А вот научиться при случае находить — полезно.

Answer (score 1):

Именование миграций не имеет значения.
Если миграция создает таблицу `items`, то её принято именовать `create_items`, при этом класс, находящийся внутри файла должен именоваться как имя файла в CamelCase, для `create_items` - класс должен иметь имя `CreateItems`.

Класс, наследуемый от `ActiveRecord::Base` называют в CamelCase, именем таблицы в единственном числе. Если таблица `items`, то класс activerecord связанный с этой таблицей будет называться `Item`.

При создании связи многие-ко-многим, например, для связи `User` и `Role`, промежуточная таблица будет называться `users_roles`(обе сущности во множественном числе). При этом класс, который связан с промежуточной таблицей будет иметь имя, состоящее из имен классов, которые связываются, в единственном числе и в CamelCase. Для таблицы `users_roles` класс будет называться `UserRole`

Подробнее можно почитать тут - http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7

Comment: а первая часть имени миграции: create,add и тд,вроде бы они а что то влияют?

Comment: @ВалерийТутаев они влияют только на понимание содержимого миграции разработчиком.

Comment: @ВалерийТутаев хм. Оказываются влияют при генерации. Смотри соседний ответ.